# Packaged application is not working when command prompt is closed

Tags: spring-boot, embedded-tomcat-8, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I was using spring boot for my application.
I deployed the jar file using the command `java -jar ...jarname.jar`.
it's working only when the command prompt or putty is open.

when I close the command prompt or putty and trying to access the service, I am getting the below exception.

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

Please let me know the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If we are talking about the Linux put ampersand after the command e.g. 'java -jar ...jarname.jar &' ... This way the command will be ran in the background and detached from console. [See here ...](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103731/run-a-command-without-making-me-wait)